# date.getHours() to calendar.hour

Tags: java, calendar

I want to get the hour of day in 24hour cycle. I know that date.getHours() is depreciated. But I'm tempted to use it since I cant get the same result out of calendar.hour call.
It seems call calendar.setTime(now) does not pick up the current date value. Anybody knows what's going on here?
much appreciated.

```
Date d = new Date();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(d);
System.out.println("hour: "+Math.abs(c.HOUR-24)+", mins: "+Math.abs(c.MINUTE-60)+", d.h: "+d.getHours() +", d.m: "+d.getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the `HOUR` and `MINUTE` *static* property of Calendar. These are used as a sort of public static enum so that when you call `Calendar.get()` or `Calendar.set()` you can refer to a specific field. To get the actual hours contained within the calendar, you should use:

```
c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```